# MS SQL Query to split the different row data in a single column into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

[image]

This shows the details of the table where it has single column and having multiple rows .I have to get the data in such a way that the rows after each DATE valued row has to be selected into different columns. for example in the table ,first row is the DATETIME followed by 3 rows with TEXT value ,then I need DATE in one column and remaining 3 rows in other columns . Totally one row wth 4 different columns. Similarly we have other rows which has one DATE row followed by single char rows or two chars rows. I had tried few queries by splitting each row in to different tables based on comman character and querying into single table using below link:

http://sqlhints.com/2013/09/07/joining-two-tables-without-any-common-column-between-them-sql-server/

However the data is not corresponding to original data..

Please help me with login por query.

Comment: First issue would be the order in which rows are going to be retrieved. Unless you have some additional column that can be used to ORDER the result, rows can be fetched in any arbitrary order. Second, is it always one row for datetime and 3 for text (meaning, always a group of 4 rows to make one row with 4 columns)?

Comment: Answer for first is : the order should be continuous followed by the date column, Second yes  always a group of 4 or more  rows to make one row with 4  or more columns

Comment: Well, unless you add some _**sequence**_ to the rows that could ensure their order during retrieval, there is no way to warrant any order at all (e.g. the chances to get all records with date first and only then all records with data is the same as that of getting the records in the correct order).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query to get the details of the table where it has single column and having multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022639/sql-server-query-to-get-the-details-of-the-table-where-it-has-single-column-and)