# SQL Server query to get the details of the table where it has single column and having multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

This shows the details of the table, where it has a single column and multiple rows. I have to output the data in such a way that the rows after each DATE valued row has to be selected into different columns.

For example, the first row in the table contains a datetime value, followed by 3 rows with a text value, so the output table should have the date in one column the values from the subsequent 3 rows in other columns associated with that datetime value. So in summary, one row with 4 different columns.

Similarly, we have other rows which have one datetime value followed by one or two rows with a text value. I had tried few queries by splitting each row in to different tables based on common character and querying into single table using the technique described in [this link](http://sqlhints.com/2013/09/07/joining-two-tables-without-any-common-column-between-them-sql-server/).

However the data is not corresponding to original data..

Please help me with logic or query. Thanks in advance.

[image: snapshot of table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways this could be done. As mentioned in [the link](http://sqlhints.com/2013/09/07/joining-two-tables-without-any-common-column-between-them-sql-server/) referenced in the question, a CTE with partitions might work, though it seems there would need to be another column that increases in sequence that could be used for the *ORDER BY* clause of the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) field .

Another way is to use a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to process the values in the table and store the results in a temp table. Use [isdate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) to check if the value is a valid date. See the example below:

```
declare @currentRow int =0;
declare @valueCol int = 1;
declare @column_mail varchar(100)
declare @results table(date1 datetime,val1 varchar(100),val2 varchar(100),val3 varchar(100), rowNum int)
declare DbCursor cursor for 

select column_mail from mail 
OPEN DBCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @column_mail
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        if (isdate(@column_mail) =1)
        BEGIN 
            set @valueCol = 1;--reset
            set @currentRow = @currentRow + 1;
            insert into @results VALUES (@column_mail,null,null,null,@currentRow)
        END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                if (@valueCol = 1) 
                    update @results set val1 = @column_mail where rowNum = @currentRow
                if (@valueCol = 2) 
                    update @results set val2 = @column_mail where rowNum = @currentRow
                if (@valueCol = 3) 
                    update @results set val3 = @column_mail where rowNum = @currentRow
                set @valueCol = @valueCol +1;       
        END 
        FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor
        INTO @column_mail
    END
CLOSE DBCursor
DEALLOCATE DBCURSOR

SELECT * FROM @results
```

Output:

[image: results output]

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks  for this help, This code works fine,.. It helped me a lot. I am trying the same with my huge data.

Comment: Hi Sam, I am facing an problem with the code .1) the data now reached 25086743 records and , the query is not able to handle this, 2)Next now i have 30-60 email ID rows after each Date row, I coulnt handle that dynamically also.     I thought of splitting the data as well into multiple tables , but since we have multiple duplicates spliting is not fool proof..Any suggestions?

Comment: Well at this point I would suggest using a scripting language like PHP and working with the data that way- perhaps you already have a scripting language that is connecting to the database?

Comment: Hi Sam, I am not sure I can use PHP at this stage. Let me go through it once again. However I have found a away in which i can split the data and use your cursor.